# Show only objects of the specified category

Tags: c#, asp.net

there is code:

Controller.cs

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
   var team = _repo.GetAllPlayers();
   return View(team);
}
```

Repository.cs

```
public List<Player> GetAllPlayers()
{
    return _ctx.Team.OrderBy(player => player.Membersince)
                    .ThenBy(player => player.Status).ToList();
}
```

Each player has a status (player.Status): owner, leader or member. I would like that only players with "Member" status would be show on the page. How can I do this? I solved this with help of HTML settings, but it's like a kludge and it's incorrect in terms of good style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<Player> GetMembers()
{
    return _ctx.Team.Where(player => player.Status == "Member")
                    .OrderBy(player => player.Membersince)
                    .ToList();
}
```